# Need more information for Network Time Protocol related daemons & commands

Tags: linux, unix, time, daemon, ntp

I've been told to execute the `ntpq` command for some reason in my work. When I look for the command on a Unix-based machine, I found more commands with one daemon:

```
[Web-01 ~]$ #ntp with <tab> key, lists commands prefixed with ntp, in a typical linux

[Web-01 ~]$ ntp
ntpd        ntpdc       ntpq        ntptime
ntpdate     ntp-keygen  ntpstat
```

Can you let me know what for `ntpq` is used for, and about all the other NTP commands.

Comment: You should know how to run `man ntpd` etc.  That tells you what's relevant to your machine.  (I'm not sure how running `ntp` listed commands with `ntp` at the start; it is more like the output from `cd /usr/bin; ls ntp*`, or something similar.)  There's (probably) only one daemon listed there; that's `ntpd`. Daemons conventionally have names ending `d`, but not all commands ending `d` are daemons and some daemons have a name not ending in `d`. I'm not sure about `ntpdc` — but to find out, I'd do what you need to do: run `man ntpdc` or search on Google with a term such as 'ntpdc program'.

Comment: some alphabets of the command and `<tab>` gives the list commands preceding with that **prefix**.... Some environment setting involved behind this..... Some of the unix machines does not gives the list by `<tab>` key.... If I get to know about the what env. setting involved behind this to ease find the commands by prefix I will get you to know.....

Comment: `ntpdc` is customized variant of `ntpq` vendor specific. I read by `--help`..... although `man` pages gives more elaborative information needed `<space>--help`  for any `unix` command is handy.

Comment: Note that `--help` is a GNU convention, not a Unix or POSIX convention; the same with `--version`.  Both are useful.  Some programs support those options even if they are not otherwise GNU programs; others use alternatives.  It is reasonable to try `-V` for version; it is less clear what to try for help, but `-h` sometimes works, and failing that, `-:` usually elicits some sort of usage message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see here for a good summary and examples:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-is-ntp-client-working/

But, in summary:

- ntpq: is to test/monitor all the NTP related daemons
- ntpd: actual daemon running in the background
- ntpstat: most useful in checking if clocks are in sync or not
- ntpdate: force a clock update

and so on and so forth.